# How verify customer presence in database during the import

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, customer, import

I've to import custumers from a txt file but I don't know what **I have to use like univocal attribute to verify the customer presence into database**.
For example, for the products import I use the sku attribute.

```
$product_model = mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                $productId = $product_model->getIdBySku($sku);
                if (!$productId){
                    // insert
                }else{
                   // update
                }
```

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess you can **check by using their email** with the following code:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->loadByEmail($customerEmail);
if ($customer->getId()) {
    // Customer exists
} else {
    // Customer doesn't exist
}
```